Stable solution for constrained system of $c$ linear equations and $n>c$ unknowns
I have multiple cases of constrain linear systems with more unknowns than equations that will find a minimum depending on which equation is used as the objective function.  Below is a minimum working example of my first approach to solving these problems.  In short it uses one of the equations as the objective function, the others constraints, and constrains the variables; does this for all equations in the system. One or more of these formulations has a solution and I select the one with the lowest L1 distance to the dependent vector.
In the example of 3 equations and 5 unknowns the 2nd and 3rd formulations have solutions with the 3rd having the lowest L1 distance to y.
Is there a method of determining which formulations will have a solution without running all of them through NMinimize?  The example below is fast but the true problem is not.
(* Min working example *) 
ClearAll["`*"]
c = 3;
n = 5;
indexX = Indexed[\[FormalX], #] & /@ Range[n];
SeedRandom[444];
coeffs = RandomReal[{5, 10}, {c, n}];
y = ConstantArray[100, c];
(* Constraints from equations *)
constraintEqs = Thread[ (y - 5) <= Flatten[coeffs . Partition[indexX, 1]] <= (y + 5)];
(* Bounds on x variables *)
xEst = RandomReal[{.3, .7}, n];
xEstBounds = {-.1, .1} + # & /@ (xEst);
boundsX = Map[1/# &, xEstBounds, {-1}];
(* Constraints on x variables *)
constraintsX = MapThread[Between, {indexX, boundsX}];
(* Objective functions *)
objectiveFoo = Flatten[coeffs . Partition[indexX, 1]] - y;
attempt =
 NMinimize[
     Flatten[{
       objectiveFoo[[#]]
       , objectiveFoo[[#]] >= 0
       , Drop[constraintEqs, {#}]
       , constraintsX
       }]
     , indexX
     , Method -> "NelderMead"
     ] & /@ Range[c] // Quiet;
(* Solutions *)
sols = Select[attempt, NumericQ@*First]


{{2.02647,{Subscript[\[FormalX], 1]->2.21338,Subscript[\[FormalX], 2]->1.86327,Subscript[\[FormalX], 3]->1.87637,Subscript[\[FormalX], 4]->3.98804,Subscript[\[FormalX], 5]->1.26568}},
 {-5.94084*10^-8,{Subscript[\[FormalX], 1]->2.86263,Subscript[\[FormalX], 2]->1.86039,Subscript[\[FormalX], 3]->2.56009,Subscript[\[FormalX], 4]->2.80994,Subscript[\[FormalX], 5]->1.46605}}}


Map[ManhattanDistance[y, #] &, Flatten[coeffs . Partition[indexX, 1]] /. sols[[All, 2]]]


{8.69865, 8.27991}



Is the objective always the L1 norm? Then one can probably reformulate this as a linear optimization problem and call LinearOptimization.

After inspecting your code I cannot match it with the text you wrote. No L1-norms show up in the code. Please clarify which problem you really want to solve.

@HenrikSchumacher The L1 distance is the ManhattanDistance in the final line that I use to pick a solution if more than one is returned.

@HenrikSchumacher I also have this as a call to LinearOptimization. The same formulations passed to it as the only difference is the objective function is the first parameter and the remainder are a list in the 2nd parameter. I use `Method->"InteriorPoint" for that call.  The issue is the same, I want to test which formulations have results instead of optimizing all of them and having some contain no result.

Aha. I see. Hm. I don't know how to do it, then. The only thing I can recommend is to reformulat the systems into nonsymbolic matrix-vector form and then call LinearOptimization[c, {Aineq, bineq}] or LinearOptimization[c, {Aineq, bineq}, {Aeq, beq}]. That should shave off a nonneglible part of the runtime.

I'm not sure if I'm understanding your constraints correctly, but we can at least use ConvexOptimization (though it may be overkill here):
obj = Norm[Inactive[Plus][coeffs . x, -y], 1];
constraints =    MapThread[Between[Indexed[x, #1], #2] &, {Range[n], boundsX}];
soln = x /. ConvexOptimization[obj, constraints, x]

@ydd Please add as an answer. Also, L1 distance (ManhattanDistance[y, coeffs . soln]) is better than the best solution in my attempt.  Please add why Inactive[Plus] is needed.

Is this actually what you want? A solution $x$ that minimizes $| Ax - y| _1$ and is within the box defined by boundsX? Because upon re-reading the question, I'm not sure if this is the answer you are looking for since you mentioned using only one  row of the matrix as the objective function, and the other as constraints, which is not what this does.

@ydd I swapped between objective functions because the NMinimize approach was not converging on every equation so I had to use all of them and pick one.  The ConvexOptimization approach does not need to single out a particular function as it takes the system as a whole.


Expanding my comment to an answer:
obj = Norm[Inactive[Plus][coeffs . x, -y], 1];
constraints = 
 MapThread[Between[Indexed[x, #1], #2] &, {Range[n], boundsX}];

And now we find the vector that minimizes the L1 - norm and meets our box constraints
soln = x /. ConvexOptimization[obj, constraints, x]

(* {2.41362, 1.86327, 1.87637, 3.98804, 1.26568} *)

ManhattanDistance[coeffs . soln, y]

(*7.10477*)

Note that this does not try to satisfy some of the equations. It just tries to minimize the L1 norm and satisfy the box constraints given by the bounds boundsX.

I've never 100% understood why to use Inactive here but this is from the ConvexOptimization documentation:

To avoid unintended threading in a.x+b, use Inactive[Plus]

Hopefully someone else sees this and they can add more on to why Inactive needs to be used here. My feeling is that it's because you don't want the vector addition to be evaluated until x has numerical values, but I don't want to sound like I am confident about this, because I am not.

Good improvement on my 1st attempt.  +1 while waiting to see if other answers emerge.
